# Community deployment via ANT migration tool?

Tags: deployment, ant, community, migration

I am trying to deploy community via ANT tool.seems like its not working.

can you explain me detail step for deploying the community via ANT ? any ref link will be helpful.

Comment: Your question is a bit non-specific. What do you mean "not working?" Do you get an error? Nothing appears? Something else? What specifically have you tried? What files are located in the package's directory? Can you include your package.xml here? It's possible you're doing something wrong, but we have no idea what that might be simply from this question.

Comment: I downloaded Meta data for community and pushing the code to destination org by ANT.Where as its saying build successful but in destination org communities are not getting created. Here is the package.xml                                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Community</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>

Comment: Is there any pre deployment steps before deploying the communities ? Can you elaborate more whats the steps we need to follow for deploying the community via ANT

Answer (score 1):

As of summer 2017, community can be deployed via changeset. Please check the below link
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets.htm?edition=&impact=